# Show matching visual selection in the current page

Tags: vim

Is there a weak visual indicator of all the texts that match the current selection? Similar to most text editors.

How I can achieve the same behavior?

Comment: what is "weak visual indicator"? There is no other text editors to a vim-er. :-D I was kidding.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly build something like that, using an `:autocmd` that obtains the current selection, and then either using default *search highlighting* (by modifying register `/`), or using `matchadd()` to add separate highlighting (but in contrast to search, that would be window-local by default). To make this robust and non-interfering with common tasks in Vim, that would be much more than a simple one-liner I could post here, though.

I must know, because I've implemented such as part of my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320). With that plugin, this can be enabled via

```
:SearchAutoHighlighting selection
```

Because my plugin contains that functionality only as a small part (of more comprehensive search tweaks and additions), also have a look at the following alternatives, which are more targeted to what you're asking for, taken from the alternatives list of my plugin:

- [highlight_word_under_cursor.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4287) implements the search
  auto-highlighting of the whole and optionally current word.
- [HiCursorWords](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4306) highlights the word under the cursor, with
  optional delay and limited to certain syntax groups.
- [Matchmaker](https://github.com/qstrahl/vim-matchmaker) highlights the word
  under the cursor with matchadd(), not the current search pattern.
- [vim-cursorword](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5100) automatically underlines the current word
  in the current window (like :SearchAutoHighlighting), but uses :match
  instead of search